# Eclipse Cygwin, Program "\xlC" not found in PATH

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, installation, cygwin

I get following error in eclipse:

> Program "\xlC" not found in PATH

I can build the program, but not run it. I already tried, disabling xcl error praser and adding path variable.

**Update:** Workaround is to install everything from cygwin, it is not really a solution, but it works now.

Comment: What C compiler have you installed?

Comment: The GNU Compiler Collection.

Comment: Then why is Eclipse looking for xlC?

Comment: When i try to run it i get the error "Program file does not exit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mention in the question one workaround is to install everything from cygwin, which is not really a solution, but it works now.

After reinstalling Windows on my laptop I reinstalled cygwin and this time everything worked fine, without the mention workaround. So there might have been an error when I first installed cygwin.